# Datasets with chronological variables for specific countries

Tags: time-series, calendar, portugal

I am doing some time-series forecasts.

The datasets that I am working on have the attributes year, month, day and hour, however, in order to deal with seasonality and holiday effects, I am looking for datasets to complement with chronological variables such as week day, holiday, week number, month number,... for specific countries (Portugal and Spain).

I am wondering where may I be able to access this kind of data, ideally historical (but for future periods is a plus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was seeing different problems regarding Holidays, I using two different approaches to build my own Holidays dataset, for the Iberian Peninsula.

[The scripts are available on this repo, on GitHub.](https://github.com/goncaloperes/TimeSeries/tree/master/IsItHoliday/IberianPeninsula)

• [In this one](https://github.com/goncaloperes/TimeSeries/blob/master/IsItHoliday/IberianPeninsula/IberianBusinessCalender.py), I have added the holidays dates manually.

• [In this one](https://github.com/goncaloperes/TimeSeries/blob/master/IsItHoliday/IberianPeninsula/holidays_prophet.py), I am taking advantage of Facebook Prophet.

In the meantime, I have also found a [library](https://github.com/dr-prodigy/python-holidays) that seeks to help generating country, province and state specific sets of holidays on the fly, however there is still a lot of room for improvement.